# How to insert into nested associative arrays in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that has a notes section that contains nested associative arrays (see schema below). I am having issues inserting a new note. Ideally I would like to do something like this

```
var label_var = '3';
db.collection.update({ _id: ObjectID(id) }, { $set: { notes.label_var : data} } ...
```

Unfortunately dot notation does not take variables and I can't use notes[label_var] in an update statement. Any help is appreciated.

Schema:

```
[
    {
        _id: GUID,
        title: 'title',
        notes: {
            '1': {
                content: 'content here'
            },
            '2': {
                content: 'content here'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your `$set` value programmatically prior to your `update` call:

```
var label_var = '3';
var set_value = {};
set_value['notes.' + label_var] = data;
db.collection.update({ _id: ObjectID(id) }, {$set: set_value}, ...);
```